# stack test Contaminating My src Dir with dump-hi files

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I am using stack and GHC 7.10.

When I run `stack test`, I end up with one `.dump-hi` file for every one of my `.hs` files. How can I prevent stack/ghc from generating these files?

Or at least make sure they are deleted by the test process after it finishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my cabal file, I have an entry in `ghc-options` in `test-suite` to include a module that I am not exposing. Well, I had been experimenting and had put the fully qualified path as:

`-i/path/to/my/project/src`

instead of just:

`-isrc`

When the fully qualified path is there, the `.dump-hi` files get generated during `stack test`, and when the relative path is there, they do not.

Why I don't know, but that was the solution.